# Change the selection color of a ListViewItem on a page level in WinRT XAML

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, listviewitem

I'm trying to change the color of a ListViewItem when it's selected. It's default color is the Windows 8 purple color.

In my App.xaml I can set the following line and this changes the selected color for the ListViews for the whole application.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Orange" />
```

However, I'd like to do this a page by page basis so I'd like to set this in the page resources.

However when I try this it's ignored and never used. It only seems to work from app.xaml.

Do anybody know how I can get round this?

This is for a windows 8 store app written in XAML and C#.

Thanks

Comment: Check out this link http://labs.vectorform.com/2012/09/styling-a-gridviewitem-in-winrt/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the visual studio xaml designer you can go in the Outline windows, click right on the the ListView in the tree, click Edit Additional Template>Edit Item Container Style>Edit a copy.
It will generate a copy of the ListViewItem Style and then you can replace ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush in this style by whatever color you want.
If there is only one color you need to change you could just used the Tag property for the color, like this you will not have to have the whole Style in each pages if you have a lot of pages each with different colors.
Here is an example:
The ListViewItem style using Tag as the selection color that you define in App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="TagListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,18,2"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                        <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                        <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionHintStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.65" To="NoSelectionHint"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="VerticalSelectionHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                        <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                        <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                        <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="0" TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="15"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.5"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.500" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="HorizontalSelectionHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                        <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                        <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectedBorder" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                        <SwipeHintThemeAnimation ToHorizontalOffset="-23" TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="0"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph">
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0.5"/>
                                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.500" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionHint"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedSwiping">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selecting">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NotDragging"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                        <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="InnerDragContent"/>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"/>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="OuterContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"/>
                                        <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText"/>
                                        <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder"/>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground"/>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"/>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="PointerOverBorder"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                            <Path x:Name="SelectingGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,9.5,9.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                            <Border x:Name="HintGlyphBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="4" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40">
                                <Path x:Name="HintGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                                <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="1" Opacity="0"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Margin="4" Opacity="0"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="4">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0" Text="Xg"/>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBorder" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4" Opacity="0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Tag}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Height="40" Opacity="0" Width="40">
                                            <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                            <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="26.667" FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="18,9,0,0" Opacity="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And then in each page you just define a Style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="OrangeListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource TagListViewItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Tag">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
     </Style>
```

If there is more than one color you need to define you could use the same principle by adding some attached properties.

Comment: Brilliant. Works just how I need it too. Thanks for your time